# change request parameters using ettercap

Tags: filter, man-in-the-middle

I am trying to modify request parameters of HTTP GET method, but the filter I wrote doesn't work as expected. I am not even sure if this is possible using ettercap. So far I wrote the following filter:

```
 if (regex(DATA.data, ".*expiration.*")){
          msg("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
          pcre_regex(DATA.data, "expiration=[0-9][0-9]*", "expiration=20150307171853");
 }
```

The message is not printed even if "expiration" appears in URL. I suspect that it would work if the pattern was contained in the body of a message, but I need to modify URL part. Is it possible to achieve that using filter or any other mechanism of ettercap?